# how to rename with the name of subfolder then copy files in python efficiently

Tags: python, list, performance, pandas, file

I have a directory in which there is multiple folder inside.
name of folder is 1, 2,3,...10.
Also there is some files inside these folders.
I want to rename the file which the name is `topics` to the name of subfolder. then copy to the one level before where 1,2,3 folders are there.

For example:

```
dir1-> 1
         topics
         cd
       2
         topics
         cd
       3
         topics
         cd
```

I want to rename name of `topics` to `1` in the `first one`
`topics` to `2` in the `second one`
`topics` to `3` in the `third one`
Also copy the newest changed name file into the `dir1`(one level back where folder 1, 2 ,3 ) are there.

I have tried this:

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(input_dir):
    for filename in files:
        #print(os.path.join(root, filename))
              if filename=='topics.csv':
                os.rename(os.path.join(root, filename), os.path.join(root, str(i)) + ".csv")
                shutil.move(os.path.join(root,str(i)), os.path.join(input_dir,str(i)))
                i = i+1
```

But it did not work.

My expected result will be

```
dir1-> 1
       1.txt
         1.txt
         cd
       2
       2.txt
         2.txt
         cd
       3
       3.txt
         2.txt
         cd
```

here `1.txt = topics` which has been renamed then coppied one level behind
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you please show your expected outcomes, if I'm not wrong that `example` is your original directory.

Comment: sure please see the updte

Comment: user2906838 I updated with the expected result thanks :)

Comment: is `1.txt` the directory name? I guess, it should be a directory name like `topics`. Sorry couldn't fathom your structure fully.

Comment: Actually 1 is the directory name, I just added .txt in the end of that. topics is file which I would like to rename to dir before it, so it is dir1-> 1> topics. so I want to rename topics and copy one level before where it is in the same level as .

Comment: `1
       topic
         1.txt
         cd` is this what you want? So what I meant is that can I suppose `1.txt` just after `1` to be a `topic` or anything but a dir?

Comment: Actually I just need to copy the topics file one level before where currently it is. the reason I d like to rename is that as all the name of files are topics so if I copy all of them in the same folder, they can not be coppied so I firstly rename the file name then copy one level before where it was. I hope its clear now

Comment: Ok, let me reproduce it, will post an answer if I manage to came up with something. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick answer. Have not thoroughly tested it, there might be some room for improvement

```
import os, shutil

input_dir = "/Users/Angela/test"
# Walk through all files in the directory that contains the files to copy
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir):

for filename in files:
    if filename == 'topics.csv':
        base = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(root))
        #Get current name
        old_name = os.path.join(base, filename)
        #Get parent folder
        parent_folder = os.path.basename(base)
        #New name based on parent folder
        new_file_name = parent_folder + ".csv" #assuming same extension
        new_abs_name = os.path.join(base, new_file_name) 
        #Rename to new name
        os.rename(old_name,new_abs_name)
        #Copy to one level up
        one_level_up = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(base, os.pardir))
        one_level_up_name = os.path.join(one_level_up, new_file_name)
        shutil.copy(new_abs_name,one_level_up_name)
```

[image]